# convert an index array to an associative array

Tags: php

I get this index array, but I need to convert this array into an associative array so that the dates become the keys of the array.

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [start_date] => 2018-03-27
            [start_time] => 10:00:00
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [start_date] => 2018-03-28
            [start_time] => 11:00:00
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [start_date] => 2018-03-28
            [start_time] => 12:00:00
        )
)
```

How can I get around the array in a loop to get the next array from it?

```
$arr = array(
    "2018-03-28" => array(
        "0" => array(
            "start_time" => "11:00:00",
        ),
        "1" => array(
            "start_time" => "12:00:00",
        )
    )
    "2018-03-27" => array(
        "0" => array(
            "start_time" => "10:00:00",
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the array and populate a new array with the times stored in elements keyed with the dates:

```
<?php

$arr = [
    0 => ['start_date' => '2018-03-27', 'start_time' => '10:00:00'],
    1 => ['start_date' => '2018-03-28', 'start_time' => '11:00:00'],
    2 => ['start_date' => '2018-03-28', 'start_time' => '12:00:00'],
];

$dates = [];
foreach ($arr as $arrItem) {
    $dates[$arrItem['start_date']][] = $arrItem['start_time'];
}

print_r($dates);
?>
```

Which gives you this:

```
Array
(
    [2018-03-27] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10:00:00
    )

    [2018-03-28] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11:00:00
        [1] => 12:00:00
    )
)
```